# Set value in DatePicker Control Template MaskedTextbox in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls, maskedtextbox

I'm a newbie to WPF not fully aware of the dependency property & stuff, I want to set the value of Datepicker to MaskedTextBox. Or is there way to mask the Datepicker textbox without using WPFToolkit/Extend it should be fine. Please help

```
<DatePicker Margin="259,12,79,270" x:Name="myDatePicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="DatePicker_TextChanged">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="myText">
                            <wpfForm:MaskedTextBox x:Name="myDatePickerText" x:Uid="myDatePickerId" Mask="00/00/0000" />
                        </WindowsFormsHost>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```